# Unexpected call to destructor in C++

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

Kindly consider the following piece code.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
  int *x;
public:
  A(int a)
  {
    cout<<"creating "<<a<<" "<<this<<endl;
    x = new int;
    *x = a;
  }

  A(A *a)
  {
    this->x = a->x;
  }

  ~A()
  {
    cout<<"destroying "<<x<<endl;
    delete x;
  }

  A *operator+(A a)
  {
    return new A(*x + *(a.x));
  }

  void display()
  {
    cout<<*x<<endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a(5);
  A b(10);
  A c = a + b;

  cout<<"control returns to main"<<endl;
  a.display();
  b.display();
  c.display();
  return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output.

```
creating 5 0xbffd6710
creating 10 0xbffd6714
creating 15 0x9273028
destroying 0x9273018
control returns to main
5
0
15
destroying 0x9273038
destroying 0x9273018
destroying 0x9273008
```

I can't understand why was the destructor invoked prior to when the control was returned to the main function. Even more importantly why was it called on `b`? If it was called on the new object returned by `operator+` it would have been understandable as destructors are called when the control comes out of the scope of the object.

Comment: copies copies copies copies copies copies copies copies copies

Comment: Try outputting `this` (instead of or in addition to `x`) in `~A`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't return a pointer from `operator+`.  Right now that's leaking.

Comment: You don't need pointers for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
A *operator+(A a)
  {
```

Receives by value. Which means when

```
a + b;
```

is encountered a new copy of `b` is created and passed to  `operator+(A a)`

You dont see a new one constructed because you don't have a copy constructor implemented and the compiler created it for you. Otherwise you will see one more A being created.

If you instead make your `operator*` take a reference like this

```
  A *operator+(A& a)
  {
    return new A(*x + *(a.x));
  }
```

You won't see the destruction anymore because no copy is created.

Answer (score 2):

You:

- don't output "creating" (or, indeed, handle your resources properly) for the *copy constructor* (which at the moment is compiler-generated)
- are seeing the temporary `a + b` get destroyed

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of the copy constructor and `+` operator are wrong.  Try this instead:

```
class A
{
private:
  int *x;
public:
  A(int a)
  {
    cout << "creating " << a << " " << this << endl;
    x = new int;
    *x = a;
  }

  A(const A &a)
  {
    cout << "copying " << *(a.x) << " " << this << endl;
    x = new int;
    *x = *(a.x);
  }

  ~A()
  {
    cout << "destroying " << *x << " " << this << endl;
    delete x;
  }

  A operator+(const A &a)
  {
    return A(*x + *(a.x));
  }

  void display()
  {
    cout << *x << endl;
  }
};
```